# Web App Configuration Settings - Best Practices

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

I was recently involved with patching a web app project and noticed the previous developer used database table for configuration settings instead of web.config (app.settings).

Which should I use? web.config or database table? Which is best?

Comment: Appreciate the additional tag, thanks Andy :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Things should go into the web.config in the following situations:

- They're things that must be available to make the database available (db connection string!)
- They're things that, if they should change, you want the application pool to refresh, or that are insanely unlikely to change.
- They're things that need to be available when the database is unavailable for any reason (such as a list of email addresses and an smtp server to send error messages to, or locations where log files belong)

Things should go into the database in the following situations:

- Both your DB and your web layer use that configuration.
- You need the ability to change the configuration on the fly, without forcing an application pool refresh.

That said - if you're going to put your config in the database you probably want to cache it in some way in the web layer so you're not hitting the db unnecessarily. I suggest the Cache class for this.

In addition to all of the above, you will also need to consider your company's policy for working with your servers. If its very, very hard for you to work with the db, it might make more sense to put things in the web.config and vice versa.

Comment: What did you mean by the following? *Both your DB and your web layer use that configuration.*

Answer (score 2):

One advantage for using a database for the settings is that things can be changed on the fly without disrupting the production website.

Changes to the web.config file will cause the worker processes on IIS to recycle and the app to be re-started.  If you are using InProcess sessions, those will be lost.  This could potentially disrupt your website users.

Answer (score 2):

We use a combination of both web.config settings and database level settings.

For each setting we ask the following question: "Is this setting specific to the machine that the application is running in?"  If it is, then it goes in the web.config.  If not, then we ask an additional question: "If this setting is changed, should the app be forced to reboot?"  If yes, web.config.  More often than not a reboot is not acceptable for our service level agreements.

Most of our applications are multi-tenant and/or run in a web farm.  Simple things like a local file system path, logging level, or database connection strings go in the web.config.  The reason is that these deal with resources specific to that machine.

Pretty much everything else is going to impact program execution and must be accessible to both the app and data layers.  Also, they tend to be needed by other applications (assuming multiple applications hit the same database).

Answer (score 1):

It it makes sense why the prev. dev used the DB for setting, go with it. You must have a web.config, I think an ASP.NET can't work without it. Project configuration setting should go into web.config (declarations of custom controls, additional assemblies etc...), but user settings or anything specific about the business logic may be better off in the database.

Comment: No I understand web.config is required but it's the app settings section I wasn't sure about. Basically I was under the impression app settings made sense - quick and easy to make changes where as db config changes is a little messier. You are right about not changing prev dev work, if it ain't broke don't change it.

Answer (score 1):

A contentious issue between developers and DBAs at my company.

In my opinion you should always use configuration files for application level, read-only settings. If the settings are user specific or editable at runtime you may or may not want to reconsider the approach.

I have seen situations where settings are stored in the database that are used internally within stored procedures. I can see some justification for this, but it’s not critical since the value can be passed to the procedures via a parameter.

Comment: Good point regards stored procs. I think having the configuration in the database makes database access a lot easier. However, this prev dev used every setting for user and app.

Answer (score 1):

One consideration may be that once the web application is deployed, the developer no longer had access to the `web.config` files in the production environment.

If he's occasionally needing to view settings to provide any form of support, putting settings in a database where he can get read-only access to a configuration table may make tons of sense.

Answer (score 1):

One use case that argues for a database is load-balanced applications, like web farms.  There may be some settings that are relevant to a single machine distinct from the other machines in the farm, that need to go in the web.config, but there will probably be a whole slew of settings that are supposed to be identical across the farm.  The farm is supposed to look like a single application from the outside, and can benefit if it can be configured like a single machine.  That means some sort of shared repository, like a database.